# Split columns cell that have no special character

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
data                    output1       output2
NSB03WH-NSB21WI         NSB03WH        NSB21WI
NSB03WH-NSB14WI         NSB03WH        NSB14WI
NSB03WH-PH45WI          NSB03WH        PH45WI
NSB01WI                                NSB01WI
NSB03WH-NSB20WH          NSB03WH        NSB20WH
T27WG                                  T27WG
```

How to get output1 and output 2?

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

Use `str.extract`:

```
df[['output1', 'output2']] = df['data'].str.extract('(?:([^-]*)-)?(.*)')
print(df)

# Output
              data  output1  output2
0  NSB03WH-NSB21WI  NSB03WH  NSB21WI
1  NSB03WH-NSB14WI  NSB03WH  NSB14WI
2   NSB03WH-PH45WI  NSB03WH   PH45WI
3          NSB01WI      NaN  NSB01WI
4  NSB03WH-NSB20WH  NSB03WH  NSB20WH
5            T27WG      NaN    T27WG
```

---

***Old answer***

Use `str.split` and `expand=True` as parameter to expand the result:

```
df[['output1', 'output2']] = df['data'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
print(df)

# Output
              data  output1  output2
0  NSB03WH-NSB21WI  NSB03WH  NSB21WI
1  NSB03WH-NSB14WI  NSB03WH  NSB14WI
2   NSB03WH-PH45WI  NSB03WH   PH45WI
3          NSB01WI  NSB01WI     None
4   SB03WH-NSB20WH   SB03WH  NSB20WH
5            T27WG    T27WG     None
```

Comment: 3-output1-should be blank and NSB01WI should be output2 and 5 should be like this

Comment: plz edit according to output

Comment: not correct, correct plz

Comment: I will fix this. I don't understand the last output row

Comment: plz look at question again, these type of value should be in output2

Comment: 5th row value sholud be in output2

Comment: Now your output is clear. I will update my answer soon

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please? Is it what you expect?